# Is it safe to move GPT formatted mdf file to MBR formatted disk?

Tags: sql-server

From our current SQL Server, I've copied a `.mdf` file to another disk (GPT to MBR).

It seems to create fault in whole disk, made MSSQLSERVICE offline.

Additionally, no error logs were unavailable while issue lasts.

However, I cannot specify if the incident was due to moving the file because incident occurred few days after moving the file.

Please help if anyone else had same symptoms or advice about what happens when moving GPT formatted `.mdf` file to MBR disk

Comment: *"no error logs were unavailable"* If none were unavailable, does that mean they were all available? Please include the logs if so.

Comment: My bad, i meant to say no error logs were available

Answer (score 1):

In general SQL Server will not care that the database files are on a GPT or MBR formatted drive. You could use could use a floppy drive if you could find one big enough to hold the database (ouch on performance though! )

The only time it will be an issue is, as @James-Jenkins mentioned, if the size of your database files exceed the limits of what am MBR formatted drive can handle. This is 2TB. For a GPT drive it's 9.4ZB (9400 Terabytes!). Windows restricts this to [256TB](https://www.maketecheasier.com/differences-between-mbr-and-gpt/).

If the MBR drive is running on a slow interface (USB1?) then you may experience IO performance issues but it shouldn't cause SQL Server to not run.

Investigate Windows system and application Logs in event [Event Viewer](https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/how-to-view-windows-application-errors-using-window-event-viewer-815567702.html) to see if there are any messages related to the drive or the IO subsystem.

Check the disk using a [testing tool](https://www.howtogeek.com/134735/how-to-see-if-your-hard-drive-is-dying/) to see if it's dying. If it's having problems you don't want to put your database on it.

Comment: thank you for the info but unfortunately, due to misconfigured setup, application logs were gone 15 min after the event happened :(
i also tried the testing tool but result showed ok.

Comment: +1 I had no idea that GPT would hold 256TB.  That is very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you would move from GPT to MBR. At least in my experience, MBR maxes out at about 2TB and GPT at about 8TB.  I often move from MBR to GPT and don't have an issue.

So I can say that MBR > GPT does not create an issue, in my environment.

I also have AlwaysOn Instances with a mix of GPT and MBR drives (ie: E drive on some servers is MBR on others it is GPT), that are not having any issues.

Your question is about moving the other way, so this may not be conclusive in your case.

Comment: Yes that is correct. I heard GPT is improved version of MBR so moving from MBR to GPT is fine. However, I was not able to find detailed results of what happens when moving GPT to MBR. I'm in a situation where i need to move the file from MDF (my server) to GPT (shared virtual storage) to MDF (my server) again due to limited space issue.